# Error: Could not find function "fwrite"

Tags: r, data.table, fwrite, microsoft-r

Am trying to export a table into a csv file using `data.table::fwrite()`

However I get the following issue when am using the command

```
library(data.table)
fwrite(DT, "location")
Error: could not find function "fwrite"
```

I had installed data.table like this

```
install.packages("data.table")
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you load `data.table`? `library(data.table)`. Also, `fwrite` is pretty new. I think it was introduced in version 1.9.8 or 1.10.0. The newest version on CRAN is 1.10.4. If you are using MS R open, then you have to specify the repository, as it will use an archive for when that version of R was released.

Comment: can you help me with the syntax?

Comment: I have 1.9.6, how can I install the new one

Comment: Yes MS R open..

Comment: Try `install.packages("data.table", repos="https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2017-03-01/")`. Note that if you are not using maintenance versions 3.1.3 or 3.2.5, you might be better off updating your version of MS R open to 3.3.2.

Comment: is it any different with this `install.packages("data.table", type = "source",
    repos = "http://Rdatatable.github.io/data.table")`